# Weird error on compiling anything, VS 2010: fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I recently installed VS 2010, for my homework assignments, but I can't get it to compile and run anything I write. If I chose an empty project, I will get this error no matter what code I write, even if code is wrong, and if I chose a non-empty project, it will not give any kind of error, even if my code is completely wrong. I was on a Windows 7 Ultimate x86, it was pretty old installation so I thought maybe it was an OS issue. So I re-installed Windows, but this time x64. Still no change, same goddamn error. I don't know what should I do, I've been searching the internet for hours but I can't find an answer. I've seen similar issues here but their answer didn't help me.

Entire error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: newproject, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 25/04/2012 10:27:00 AM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\newproject.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ManifestResourceCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mainCRTStartup
1>C:\Users\Milad\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\newproject\Debug\newproject.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.85
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout<<"test";
        return 0;    
}
```

Comment: So, `int main(){}` won't compile?

Comment: What's the unresolved external?

Comment: Show a specific example:  source code, command you are typing, entire output.

Comment: ta.speot.is you are asking me? lol

Comment: My code is just a hello world program. I can't get the damn thing to compile anything! I just get this error.

Comment: If you get that error, it will usually follow a list of the undefined symbols.

Comment: Entire error and program code added.

Comment: Please select **Win32 Console Application** under new projects.

Answer (score 0):

You need to link to the c runtime, probably msvcr100.  I haven't got VC 2010 to hand and haven't used it for a while, but usually you get that by default.

Maybe you should select win32 console project, rather than empty project: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235629.aspx

There's more information here about the C Runtime: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh.aspx